# pandas: fill multiple empty dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm declaring multiple empty dataframes as follows:

```
variables = pd.DataFrame(index=range(10),
                           columns=['P1', 'P2', 'P3'],
                          dtype='float64')

Q1 = pd.DataFrame(index=range(10),
                   columns=['P1H1', 'P1H2'],
                   dtype='float64')
```

I can use fillna as follows:

```
variables = variables.fillna(0)
Q1 = Q1.fillna(0)
```

What is a more pythonic way of filling multiple dataframes simultaneously ?

---

Reason: Here I have given only two dataframes, however, the real problem has many more dataframes, which I have to update periodically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `for` loop:

```
for df in (variables, Q1):
    df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Would this require the `inplace=True` parameter?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can fill columns in `DataFrame contructor` with `0`, then `fillna` can be omited :

```
import pandas as pd

variables = pd.DataFrame(index=range(10),
                         columns=['P1', 'P2', 'P3'],
                         data={'P1':[0],'P2':[0],'P3':[0]},
                         dtype='float64')

print variables   
    P1   P2   P3
0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1  0.0  0.0  0.0
2  0.0  0.0  0.0
3  0.0  0.0  0.0
4  0.0  0.0  0.0
5  0.0  0.0  0.0
6  0.0  0.0  0.0
7  0.0  0.0  0.0
8  0.0  0.0  0.0
9  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

```
Q1 = pd.DataFrame(index=range(10),
                  columns=['P1H1', 'P1H2'],
                  data={'P1H1':[0],'P1H2':[0]},
                  dtype='float64')
print Q1                   
   P1H1  P1H2
0   0.0   0.0
1   0.0   0.0
2   0.0   0.0
3   0.0   0.0
4   0.0   0.0
5   0.0   0.0
6   0.0   0.0
7   0.0   0.0
8   0.0   0.0
9   0.0   0.0
```

Also, parameter `columns` can be omited:

```
import pandas as pd

variables = pd.DataFrame(index=range(10),
                         data={'P1':[0],'P2':[0],'P3':[0]},
                         dtype='float64')

Q1 = pd.DataFrame(index=range(10),
                  data={'P1H1':[0],'P1H2':[0]},
                  dtype='float64')
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that your dtype and index is the same, you can use a dictionary comprehension where each dataframe is a value in the dictionary.

```
cols = {'variables': ['P1', 'P2', 'P3'],
        'Q1': ['P1H1', 'P1H2']}

dfs = {key: pd.DataFrame(index=range(10), columns=cols[key], dtype='float64').fillna(0) 
       for key in cols}
```